# Convert string to array in Ruby on rails

Tags: arrays, ruby, string

I am having string:

```
str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
```

I want to convert this to an array:

```
arr = [[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A JSON parser ought to work fine:

```
require "json"

str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
p JSON.parse(str)
# => [[591, 184], [741, 910], [987,512], [2974, 174]]
```

Try it on eval.in: https://eval.in/777054

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this:

```
str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
reg = /(?<=\[)[\d,?\s?]+(?=\])/
str.scan(reg).map { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
#=> [[591, 184], [741, 910], [987, 512], [2974, 174]]
```

or taking a leaf out of @Jordan's book, but using YAML:

```
require 'yaml'
str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
YAML.load(str) #=> [[591, 184], [741, 910], [987, 512], [2974, 174]]
```

Comment: I'm confused about the character class `[\d,?\s?]+`. In a character class question marks are taken literally, so this will match one or more digits, commas, question marks, or whitespace characters.

Answer (score 2):

I would `split` and `scan` in two steps.

```
str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"

str.split(/\]\s*,\s*\[/).map { |s| s.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
  #=> [[591, 184], [741, 910], [987, 512], [2974, 174]]
```

Note that

```
str.split(/\]\s*,\s*\[/)
  # => ["[[591, 184", "741, 910", "987,512", "2974, 174]]"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use "eval":

```
> str = "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
# => "[[591, 184] , [741, 910] , [987,512], [2974, 174]]"
> arr = eval str
# => [[591, 184], [741, 910], [987, 512], [2974, 174]]
```

Comment: Although technically true, `eval` is an absolute last resort. Since this data is valid JSON, Jordan has a better idea.